# How inject data after every certain count in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some SQL data which I am fetching from the database, I am using angular js with an **ng-repeat** directive to list all rows below is my code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content" ng-repeat="row in rows">
        {{row.someData}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now I have some custom advertisement banners which I want to show after every 4th row but I don't know how to it with angular Js so please help me here

Comment: Use `ng-if="$index % 4 === 0"`.

Comment: You can use something like `ng-if="!($index % 4) && !$first"

Comment: yes I know about the ng-if directive can you give an example working code for injecting new HTML data after every 4th index

Comment: please don't minus vote i have searched whole google and still did not find a good solution i hope you will help me here

Comment: If the code works I will mark it as solved please help me here

Comment: Not much needed. Others have already shown you the `ng-if`. Just put that on an element and put your content inside it

Comment: yes but i don't have common data i have diffent differnt banners after every 4th index

Comment: what i am doing is first i am loading all sql data then i am sending secnd http request for ad banners now i want to inject those ad banners in already loaded sql data got my point ?

Comment: @VikasKandari You have been given the right answer for your question.  If it isn't answering your actual question then your question is not well written.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Panos K's way what you can do is have one flag to check if banner data is received from web service and then add it after every 4th row of data already loaded. So, for that have `ng-if` condition inside `ng-repeat` & then bind that new bannerData arry/objects with index as `$index/4`.

Check below Plunker example I've created to demonstrate this. Click on Banner data button to make async call to get banner data & then binding it to existing data loaded using ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records track by $index">
    <div class="column">{{x.name}}</div>
    <div class="column">{{x.abbreviation}}</div>
    <div ng-if="isBannerDataAvailable && ($index+1) % 4 === 0" class="banner">
        <p>Banner After every 4th row</p>
        <p> {{showBannerData($index)}} </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where showBannerData() can be:

```
$scope.showBannerData = function($index) {
    var index = $scope.Math.round(($index + 1) / 4) - 1;
    return $scope.bannerData[index].Banner;
}
```

**[Working plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/DcnzLJ3TIw3tJE1WhrJw?p=preview)**

Comment: this is the correct answer if he wants to have flexibility on his banner formats, keeping separate model for banners will make it much easier to handle

Answer (score 0):

First edit your question with your last comment.
what you need to do is add banners to your model ($scope.rows in your case)
So when you fetch your banners (onSuccess) do this

```
banners.forEach((element,index)=>{
  if(index%4==0)
  $scope.rows.splice(index,0,element); 
})
```